# Why can't I create an array of a generic type?

Tags: java, language-design

In short, this won't compile:

```
public <A> void test() {
    A[] temp = new A[]{};
}
```

Is it because of problems with backward compatibility, or is it something fundamental in the language design that prevents it?

Comment: "is it something fundamental in the language design that prevents it?"   - apparently, yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bottom line is that the class that represents the array has to know the component type.  Hence the method on the Class object:

```
public Class<?> getComponentType()
Returns the Class representing the component type of an array. If this class does not represent an array class this method returns null.
```

So when you would try:

```
 A[] a = new A[0];
```

At compile time, it's obvious that we don't know the type, as it's a generic parameter.  At runtime, we don't know the type due to type erasure.  So instantiating the array is impossible.

Think of the above statement as equivalent to:

```
 A[] a = (A[])Array.newInstance(???, 0);
```

And due to type erasure, we can't get the class of A at runtime.

It was asked why not have the compiler reduce to Object[] or Number[] or something like that?

It's because a different Class will be returned depending on the component type.  So:

```
 new Object[0].getClass() 
 new Integer[0].getClass()
```

are not the same class.  In particular the "getComponentType()" method on the class would return different values.

So if you reduce it to Object[] instead of A[], you're not actually getting back something of type A[], you're getting back Object[].  Object[] cannot be cased to Integer[] and will yield a ClassCastException.

Comment: Is there a difference between `A[] a` for type parameter `<A>` and `Object[] a` in the byte code or is both compiled to the same byte code?

Comment: There's not the same, because the resulting call to a.getClass() would yield different Class instances.  I'll edit to explain

Comment: I got many good answers, and I upvoted all of them, but I think this one was the cleanest in depth answer.

Answer (score 5):

Type [erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) is the word you are looking for. It basically means that the [generic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) information is erased at compile time. The main reason for this is backward compatibility. Older programs should still run on the new java virtual machine.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, the type system for arrays and generics is incompatible.
There are two main areas of discrepancy: **dynamic vs static type check** and  **covariance**.

Generics are statically checked: that is, the compiler makes sure that the type definitions are coherent. "Type erasure" was a compromise to ensure backwards-compatibility in the JVM. After compilation, generic type definition is no longer available. E.g. `List<T>` becomes `List`.

In contrast, arrays are dynamically type-checked. Consider the following example:

```
String strings[] = {"a","b","c"};
Object simple[] = strings;
simple[0] = new Object(); // Runtime error -> java.lang.ArrayStoreException
```

Covariance is the inheritance relationship of a container based on the content.
Given types A,B and a container C, if B isAssignableFrom(A) => C isAssignable C.

Arrays in Java are covariant, in the previous example, Given that `Class<Object>.isAssignableFrom(Class<String>) => Object[] is assignable from String[]`

In contrast, generic types are not covariant in Java. Using the same example:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Object> objectList = stringList; // compiler error - this is not allowed.
```

Given the type erasure of the generics implementation, type information is lost in translation and therefore the dynamic type check would be compromised if you could create an array of a generic type.

Further read on the complications and implications of these issues: [Arrays in Java Generics](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/Papers/JavaGenerics/ArraysInJavaGenerics.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work for the same (or almost the same) reason that `new A()` can't work: you are expecting the compiler to know the runtime type of `A`, which it clearly cannot know. This *would* work if Java Generics were like C++ templates, where new code is generated for each instantiation of the template involving `A`.

Comment: In what way is it similar to `new A()`? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @aioobe `A[]` is a distinct type, just as `A` itself. An instance of it knows its type. This is very unlike `List<A>`, which is at runtime just a `List`.

Comment: Sure, but `new A[] {}` doesn't involve creating any objects. The connection to `new A()` is not clear to me.

Comment: @aioobe How do you figure that? There is no occurence of `new` in Java that **doesn't** involve creating objects. `new A[0]` creates one new object of type `A[]`.

Comment: Sure, but an *array* us just an array :-)

Comment: @aioobe That is not correct. Every array type is a distinct type, and their hierarchy follows the hierarchy of element type. Primitive arrays are separate islands, just as the primitives themselves.

Comment: The difference is `new A()` requires a default constructor, while `new A[]{}` doesn't. So I think it is not the same.

Comment: E.g. for `<A>` `new A[]{}` could be compiled to `new Object[]{}` and for `<A extends Number>`to `new Number[]{}`.

Comment: @Puce Notice the parethesized word **almost** in my answer. It is there for exactly this reason.

Comment: @Puce:  no, it couldn't be compiled to new Object[] { }.  See my answer below regarding getComponentType() on the Class object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a fundamental reason, which boils down to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Consider the following snippet:

```
A[] temp = new A[5];       // Assume this would compile.

Object[] objects = temp;   // This is allowed, since A extends Object.

objects[0] = new String(); // This does *not* throw an ArrayStoreException
                           // due to type erasure since the original type of A
                           // is now Object.

A t = temp[0];             // Now this seemingly innocent line would *fail*.
```

**Related question:**

- [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)

Comment: You will have the same issue for `List<Foo> fooList;` and then pass `fooList.toArray(new Foo[fooList.size()])` to `public <A> void test(A[] as);`Generics and arrays just don't fit well as arrays are not type-safe.